# Volumetric lighting fix

Tags: shaders, lighting, lightprobe

I want to make a volumetric light that comes from into a box but in a bright room like this:[image]

But when i use volumetric scatter or other nodes to my scene,the light doesn't appear and my render gets in trouble.
What can i do???anybody knows?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a beam effect with a cone (or whatever shape you want) that has a mix between *Emission* and *Transparent* nodes, with a *Layer Weight* as factor. I've added a gradient on Z so that it decays vertically:

[image]

[image]